# Plot Dataframe with bokeh multi_line

Tags: python, plot, dataframe, bokeh

I have a DataFrame.from_dict which I would like to plot each of the series on the same figure using Bokeh.

I believe I will have to make use of multi_line. Each Column of my DataFrame is a number (from the key in the dict, see below)) and the values are tuples where the first index is the x value, and the second is the y value. They all share the same x axis, so I'd like to overlay each of the Y values (for each column) on the same figure.

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data = dictionary_data)
p.multi_line(df,line_color=mypalette,line_width=5)

show(p)

          0                  101                  481   
0   (100.0, 15040.0)   (100.0, 30080.0)  (100.0, 22229120.0)   
1       (200.0, 0.0)       (200.0, 0.0)   (200.0, 3579520.0)   
2   (300.0, 15040.0)       (300.0, 0.0)   (300.0, 8272000.0)   
3       (400.0, 0.0)   (400.0, 15040.0)   (400.0, 1218240.0)   
4       (500.0, 0.0)       (500.0, 0.0)  (500.0, 30756800.0)   
5       (600.0, 0.0)       (600.0, 0.0)   (600.0, 8226880.0)   
6   (700.0, 15040.0)   (700.0, 15040.0)   (700.0, 3549440.0)   
7       (800.0, 0.0)       (800.0, 0.0)   (800.0, 6978560.0)   
8       (900.0, 0.0)       (900.0, 0.0)   (900.0, 4872960.0)   
9  (1000.0, 15040.0)  (1000.0, 15040.0)  (1000.0, 5715200.0)   

           2006                  8191  
0  (100.0, 15040.0)    (100.0, 9024000.0)  
1      (200.0, 0.0)   (200.0, 27643520.0)  
2      (300.0, 0.0)   (300.0, 22951040.0)  
3      (400.0, 0.0)   (400.0, 29989760.0)  
4      (500.0, 0.0)     (500.0, 481280.0)  
5      (600.0, 0.0)   (600.0, 23011200.0)  
6      (700.0, 0.0)   (700.0, 27643520.0)  
7  (800.0, 15040.0)   (800.0, 24244480.0)  
8      (900.0, 0.0)   (900.0, 26365120.0)  
9     (1000.0, 0.0)  (1000.0, 25477760.0)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?